# Video Start/End Times in YouTube App

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

**Question: Is it possible to get the YouTube mobile app to respect the start-time and end-parameters when opening a YouTube URL?**

Example: The following link respects the `start` and `end` parameters when opened with Windows-Chrome or Android-Chrome. But it ignores those parameters when opened with the Android YouTube App.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/FmaiitpA2kc?start=45&end=50&modestbranding=1&rel=0

*NB: I am not asking how to specify the start/end time for a YouTube video in general. I am not asking about any Android embed implementation. I am specifically asking whether or not there is a way to get the YouTube mobile app to respect the `start` and `end` parameters when opening a URL with the app.*

Answer (score 0):

No, Youtube app have the start-time and the end-time together not yet, and it just play with embed of webstite.Youtube app just only play with starttime.